# Force update React sibings

Tags: reactjs, updates, siblings

how can I make a component to force update its sibling. Currently my component rerenders on componentDidMount but this happens on a selection from a drop down.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're incurred in this type of problem I suppose you do not use Redux or similar. The easiest way is to lift the state to the common parent component:

Doc ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I use Redux but because the page doesn't reload the effect never happens.. or I am doing something wrong. The reducer encounters the change the component doesn't display it.

Comment: Redux sync works (as normal state) without reloading through mapStateToProps. Each change to state or Redux state will result in a re-render of the view.

Comment: yes  but I am making the change only in componentDidMount

Comment: when you set the state in componentDidMount the application is already rendered, the when state's changed, it renders AGAIN. It seems you have not clear some basic react patterns

Answer (score 0):

If `Comp1` and `Comp2` are siblings and `Parent` is the common parent for the two siblings
You can pass a callback function from Parent to `Comp1`, whenever `Comp1` is updated it can notify the `Parent` via the callback prop.
In parent you can listen to props change using componentwillreceiveprops and re render the `Comp2` using the changed props again passed to it from the Parent.

or in a more complicated appliation set up, you can use `redux` to store into a global state.